# div:nth-child(0) doesn't work

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to change css attributes of a certain child div inside another div using nth-child index selector, but for some reason no changes occur.

```
<div class="itemgrid">
    <div class="insideitem"></div>
    <div class="insideitem"></div>
    <div class="insideitem"></div>
    <div class="insideitem"></div>
</div>

.itemgrid{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    font-style:inherit;
}


.itemgrid div:nth-child(2) :{
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #dedede;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You realise that there's either a syntax error or a typo in your code, the stray colon shouldn't be there (before the final `{`).

Comment: It's always something like that, thank you!

Comment: @MuradNabiev Was that the problem?

Comment: Consider using a CSS linter to pick up typographical, and syntax, errors. Such as: http://csslint.net/ (for example).

Comment: yes that was the problem

Answer (score 4):

It happens because index of the 1st child is 1 not 0. See [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Also you need to wrap your CSS code in `<style>` tag.

Just change your CSS code to:

```
<style>
    .itemgrid{
        width:100%;
        display:block;
        font-style:inherit;
    }


    .itemgrid div:nth-child(1) {
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #dedede;
        border-style: solid;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: It doesn't work with any index number. I tried 1 and 2 - still no result. I edited my question as well.

Comment: I use separate css file and styling works perfectly, I have an issue only with this particular selector.

Comment: You' re persisting a typo, the stray `:` should *not* be there at all.

Comment: Then it's typo issue. See semicolon before {

Comment: @DavidThomas yeah. Just realized it's all due to typo.

Answer (score 2):

because it counts from 1 :

```css
.itemgrid{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    font-style:inherit;
}


.itemgrid div:nth-child(1){
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #dedede;
    border-style: solid;
    color : red;
}
```

```html
<div class="itemgrid">
    <div class="insideitem">Hello</div>
    <div class="insideitem">my</div>
    <div class="insideitem">dear</div>
    <div class="insideitem">friend</div>
</div>
```

Comment: While you're correct, so far as you've gone, the error is likely to have been the typo - that you've corrected in your own code - that you didn't mention in your answer. Also you've effectively reproduced the same content already featured in the other existing answers.

Comment: because there is only one answer

Comment: and this is what we posted !

Answer (score 1):

In css there is no 0th child, count starts from 1
if you are targeting to style the firstelement , use either first-child or nth-child(1)

```css
.itemgrid{
    width:100vw;
    display:block;
    font-style:inherit;
    color:red;
}


.itemgrid div:nth-child(1) {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #dedede;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="itemgrid">
    <div class="insideitem">div-1</div>
    <div class="insideitem">dov=2</div>
    <div class="insideitem">div-3</div>
    <div class="insideitem">div-4</div>
</div>
```